# Percent sign after Smarty variable

Tags: php, smarty

in my setup double percent signs are variable delimiters (i.e.%%first_name%%). I'd like to have a percent sign after the inputted variable but it always seems to break when i try %%percent%%%. How can I insert a percent sign after the variable?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you are using Smarty? Variables should start with dollar sign `$` and I'm pretty sure that Smarty does not work if left and right delimiters are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if

```
&#37;
```

working in this case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try escaping the one you want?

```
%%percent%%\%
```

You *may* need to escape the backslash also, though I doubt it in this scenario, that's usually something that comes into play with regular expressions because you need to pass the backslash in as a literal part of the expression.

```
%%percent%%\\%
```

Answer (score 0):

There's what [`literal`](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.escaping.tpl) is for, so it should look like this:

```
%%$variable%%%%literal%%%%%/literal%%
```

but that looks so wrong that I'm not recommending to use it.